# How to sum the values from a field in subdocuments from an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

How do I project only the words found in each document from any of the keywords provided? The structure of the document is as follows:

```
{
    _id: 24752893,
    dictionary: [
        {
            word: 'word1',
            count: 2,
        },
        {   
            word: 'word2',
            count: 5,
        },
        {
            word: 'word4',
            count: 1,
        },
        ....
    ]
},
{
    _id: 6786765789,
    dictionary: [
        {
            word: 'word4',
            count: 3,
        },
        {
            word: 'word2',
            count: 6,
        },
        {
            word: 'word3',
            count: 3,
        },
        {
            word: 'word5',
            count: 1,
        },
        ....
    ]
},
........
{
    _id: 76675567,
    dictionary: [
        {
            word: 'word1',
            count: 7,
        },
        {
            word: 'word3',
            count: 2,
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

If a list of keywords like **['word2', 'word3']** is given, and a document should be retrieved whenever any of the words in the keyword list is found in it. I have written this aggregation pipeline to get the necessary documents:

```
client.database.collection.aggregate([
    {
    '$project': {
        '_id': 1,
        'dictionary': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$dictionary',
                'as': 'words',
                'cond': {
                    '$in': [
                        '$$words.word', keywords
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    }
},
{
    '$match': {
        'dictionary': {
            '$ne': []
        }
    }
},
,
{
    '$unwind': '$dictionary'
},
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'score': {
            '$sum': '$dictionary.count'
        }
    }
}
])
```

What I want to do is instead of projecting the whole dictionary, I want to project only the matching words for each document along with its count. And of course, I want the dictionary for each document to be in separate projected documents. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter your arrays, try this:

```js
let keywords = ['word2', 'word3']

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            dictionary: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$dictionary",
                    as: "word",
                    cond: {
                        $in: ["$$word.word", keywords]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [{ $size: "$dictionary" }, 0]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "dictionary" : [
        {
            "word" : "word2",
            "count" : 5
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "dictionary" : [
        {
            "word" : "word2",
            "count" : 6
        },
        {
            "word" : "word3",
            "count" : 3
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 */
{
    "dictionary" : [
        {
            "word" : "word3",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this pipeline is providing the correct result, but it's also returning the documents where the keywords are not present with an empty array. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Put a `$mtch` condition with empty array check.

Comment: can I get the sum of the values from each dictionary field? I tried to do it using $group stage on the '_id' field, But I could not find a way to get a separate sum of counts for each document. I have changed the pipeline that I tried.

Comment: What is your MongoDb version?

Comment: I am using version 4.4.4, the latest version

Comment: Check the updated answer with `$match` stage. Is it working?

Comment: $match with $expr worked much slower than the $match stage I wrote. But the result was the same.

Comment: Have you created indexes for the necessary fields.

Comment: Are you aware of this  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/ ?

Comment: I have the 'dictionary.word' field indexed. And the real data is very large in size, not suitable to share that. This example is a demo following the actual schema. I have updated the pipeline I have so far. This works fine for adding the values. And I am not very clear about cursor methods.